# Python +selenium Json File Web bot iteration

Tags: python, json, selenium

Im building a Web bot for footlocker and i just need to iterate through my JSON object so that i can Fill in the Form field on the check out page!

Im using Selenium to perform these tasks and until it gets up to the check out page it fills out 2 - 3 of the elements and then it just stops and returns an error when i print out the for loop and see what I am returning it will just give me 4 elements and the JSON file has 8 fields 
the code will be below along with the JSON file and the error message i will edit out the original checkout selenium code and just leave the print statement please help!

json code

```
{
"billFirstName":"rashawn",
"billLastName":"doyley",
"billAddress1":"1 newb st",
"billPostalCode":"1112",
"billCity":"millburn",
"billState":"nj",
"billHomePhone":"7184459582",
"billEmailAddress":"rashawndoyley@gmail.com"
}
```

python code

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import json
from pprint import pprint

def get_page(model, sku):
    url = "https://www.footlocker.com/product/model:"+str(model)+"/sku:"+ str(sku)+"/"
    return url

data = json.load(open('info.json'))

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

page=browser.get(get_page(277097,"8448001"))

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pdp_size_select_mask']").click()

shoesize = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.grid_size:nth-child(8)')))

shoesize.click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pdp_addtocart_button']").click()

browser.get('https://www.footlocker.com/shoppingcart/default.cfm?sku=')

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#cart_checkout_button').click()
'''
ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='billFirstName']")))

add = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='billFirstName']").click()
print(add.is_displayed());


'''


for info, value in data.items():
    ele = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 90).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='"+info+"']")))
    print(info)
    #ele.click()
    #ele.clear()
    #ele.send_keys(value)
'''
ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='billAdress1']")))
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='billAdress1']").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='billAdress1']").clear()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='billAdress1']").send_keys("user_first_name")
#ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "billFirstName")))
'''
#browser.find_element_by_id("#billFirstName").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#firstname = browser.find_element_by_id('#billFirstName')

#ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "#billFirstName")))

#browser.find_element_by_id("#billFirstName").send_keys(" and some", Keys.ARROW_DOWN)


#finish this code and getting json
```

Error message  and printed out message

```
billCity
billFirstName
billEmailAddress
billLastName
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fl_bot.py", line 42, in <module>
    ele = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 90).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='"+info+"']")))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```